# WifiPhisher not creating a fake access point

Tags: passwords, wifi, phishing

I recently came to know about WifiPhisher. To test it, I set up an access point using my Windows laptop and tried to obtain its password using this tool in my Ubuntu machine. So, when I run the program, it can cause Denial of Service by sending deauth packets to the AP I have created, but it does not create its fake access point, which can cause Evil Twin attack. So, does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: what is the attacker machine? is it VM? what kind of WiFi adapter are you using? does the program say any error? ... please be more clear